# Qt Creator version 4.9.2: Filter output in Application Output pane

Tags: qt, logging, plugins, qt-creator, qtwidgets

Does anyone out there know of a `Qt Creator` plugin that will give me the ability to filter debug output (based on a string pattern) in `Applicaiton Output` pane during debugging. This is a common feature in logging applications, but in many cases it's much easier to use the log from within `Qt Creator.`

The app I'm currently working on creates a new log file upon every launch, so using a conventional logger is not convenient for me.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently for version `4.9.2` there is no straightforward solution to this problem other than relying on an external logger. I installed `Qt Creator` version `4.10.0` and it does allow filtering of the output pane.

[image]